# how do you plot multiple functions on one single graph when run on specific data points

Tags: r, plot

I know how to plot multiple functions on one graph,

```
  > var1 <- function(x) x^2
  > var2 <- function(x) x*(log(x)^2)
  > var3 <- function(x) x*log(x)
  > plot(var1,var2,var3, type="l",col="blue",xlim=c(0,40),
  + xlab="X-axis",ylab="Y-axis", add=TRUE)
```

How to plot these together with points when x = 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 on each functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
xs <- c(2, 4, 8, 16, 32)
curve(var1, col = "blue", xlim = c(0, 40), xlab = "X-axis", ylab = "Y-axis")
curve(var2, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
curve(var3, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
points(xs, var1(xs), col = "blue")
points(xs, var2(xs), col = "blue")
points(xs, var3(xs), col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: neat! this gives the points only. i guess i can use `lines` if i want points with functions all together?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ggplot2` approach.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(2, 4, 8, 16, 32)
var1 <- x^2
var2 <- x * log(x) ^ 2
var3 <- x * log(x)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(x, times = 3), y = c(var1, var2, var3), var = rep(c("var1", "var2", "var3"), each = length(x)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = var)) + geom_line()
```

Replace `geom_line()` with `geom_point()` if you want points instead of lines, and add `+ geom_point()` at the end if you want points and lines.

[image]

Comment: TO get points as well add `+ geom_point()` to @blakeoft's answer:

    ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = var)) + geom_line() + geom_point()

Answer (score 1):

```
var1 = function(x) x^2
var2 = function(x) x*(log(x)^2)
var3 = function(x) x*log(x)

curve(var1,0,40)
curve(var2,add = T, col="red")
curve(var3,add = T, col="blue")

x=c(2, 4, 8, 16, 32)

points(x,var1(x))
points(x,var2(x), col="red")
points(x,var3(x), col="blue")
```